# Taylor expansion without entire Hessian matrix

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion

In Taylor expansion we use the Hessian matrix to write

$$f(x+p) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^Tp + \frac{1}{2}p^T \nabla^2f(x+tp)p.$$

Instead of using the entire Hessian $\nabla^2f (x)$ matrix can we use the diagonal of $\nabla^2f (x)$, i.e.,

$$\text{diag} \nabla^2 f (x) \stackrel{\Delta}{=} \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\partial^2 f (x)}{\partial x_1^2} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{\partial^2 f (x)}{\partial x_2^2} & \dots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & \dots & \frac{\partial^2 f (x)}{\partial x_d^2}
  \end{pmatrix},$$
to define Taylor expansion, i.e.,

$$f(x+p) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^Tp + \frac{1}{2}p^T \text{diag} \nabla^2f(x+tp)p \quad ?$$
Is there any way to justify the validity of using the diagonal of $\nabla^2f(x)$? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If $f(x,y)=xy$, the Taylor expansion (around the origin) with the diagonal part of the Hessian will give $0$. So no. The only way I see is to rotate coordinates accordingly so that the Hessian is diagonal (possible since the Hessian is a real symmetric matrix, so the Spectral theorem can be applied).

Comment: @peek-a-boo The Hessian is symmetric as you said. Thus, there is $Q$ such that $Q^T H Q = \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ a diagonal matrix. Also, let $y = Q^Tp$. Then the Taylor is,

$$f(x+Qy) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^TQy + \frac{1}{2}y^T \Sigma y.$$ It this what you mean? Can we write it better?

Comment: I think that you can find good explanation of this if you look up the paper on Adam optimizer, something like this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360322/what-does-diagonal-rescaling-of-the-gradients-mean-in-adam-paper

Comment: @peek-a-boo is this always the case when the problem is high dimensional?

Comment: Oh i didn't see the previous comment. Yes that's what I meant, and yes in high dimensions it's usually hard to "reduce the complexity"; eg choosing the right coordinates is difficult.